# How to fix this exception shown in windbg execution?

Tags: c#, c++, windbg

after running the .exe thought WinDBG, this was the exception information provided by pressing "k" when the exception occured:

```
ChildEBP RetAddr  
0012e2f4 6f9fbb1c KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x58
0012e354 6fba88f4 mscorwks!RaiseTheExceptionInternalOnly+0x2a8
0012e36c 6fba8966 mscorwks!RaiseTheException+0x4e
0012e394 6fba8997 mscorwks!RaiseTheException+0xc0
0012e3c0 6fba89a5 mscorwks!RealCOMPlusThrow+0x30
0012e3d0 6fac7ffe mscorwks!RealCOMPlusThrow+0xd
0012e8c8 6fa9d308 mscorwks!MethodTable::DoRunClassInitThrowing+0x44c
0012e914 6f9f8b9b mscorwks!DomainFile::Activate+0x226
0012e920 6f9cc537 mscorwks!DomainFile::DoIncrementalLoad+0xb4
0012e9a4 6f9cc43e mscorwks!AppDomain::TryIncrementalLoad+0x97
0012e9f4 6f9cd449 mscorwks!AppDomain::LoadDomainFile+0x19d
0012ea6c 6fb40e1a mscorwks!AppDomain::LoadDomainAssembly+0x116
0012eab0 6fb148c4 mscorwks!AppDomain::LoadExplicitAssembly+0x43
0012ed24 6fb167be mscorwks!ExecuteDLLForAttach+0x109
0012edd4 6fb16e9b mscorwks!ExecuteDLL+0x197
0012ee20 704c71f8 mscorwks!CorDllMainForThunk+0x8d
0012ee38 704ca1fe MSCOREE!CorDllMainWorkerForThunk+0x50
0012ee48 704bb2dc MSCOREE!VTableBootstrapThunkInitHelper+0x1b
0012eec8 7726519a MSCOREE!VTableBootstrapThunkInitHelperStub+0xc
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
0012eed0 7726517e ntdll!RtlpNtMakeTemporaryKey+0x43d6
0012eed4 770116fc ntdll!RtlpNtMakeTemporaryKey+0x43ba
0012ef10 77227d96 RPCRT4!DG_CCALL::DispatchPacket+0x1e3
0012ef14 014b1628 ntdll!RtlTimeToElapsedTimeFields+0xe902
0012ef18 00000000 0x14b1628
```

Does anyone knows what does this mean? And how can I solve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it is a 3.5 or lower .NET then you have to load sos by calling ".loadby sos mscorwks". If it is a 4.0 then you have to use ".loadby sos clr".

Answer (score 3):

What you're seeing is the *unmanaged* stack that's handling a *managed* exception. I suggest you do the following:

```
.load sos
!CLRStack
```

The first line will load SOS.dll, which allows for debugging of managed code. The second will print the managed stack trace. You can also use `!help` to see what other commands are available. For more information, see this MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6d2sxs.aspx.

Comment: I can't call !CLRStack, it gives an error:
0:000> !CLRStack
No export CLRStack found

How can I solve this?

Comment: @af, what messages did you get when you did `.load sos`?

Comment: @JSBᾶngs if he's like me, he got:

0:034> .load sos
The call to LoadLibrary(sos) failed, Win32 error 0n2
    "The system cannot find the file specified."
Please check your debugger configuration and/or network access

Comment: @Tom, if that's the exception that you got, then I recommend that you use the command given in the accepted answer.